# Trouble with pseudocode and integrating methods

Tags: logic, pseudocode

Create the logic for a program that continuously prompts the user for a numeric value until the user enters 0. The application passes the value in turn to a method that computes the sum of all the whole numbers from 1 up to and including the entered numbers, and to a method that computes the product of all the whole numbers up to and including the entered number.

So far, this is what I have:

```
BEGIN
  MAIN MODULE BEGIN
    Declare enteredNumber as Integer
    Do While (enteredNumber != 0)
    DISPLAY "Enter a positive number (0-EXIT) : "
    input enteredNumber
    sumModule(enteredNumber)
      OUTPUT enteredNumber
    productModule(enteredNumber)
      OUTPUT enteredNumber
    EndWhile
  END MAIN MODULE

sumModule(enteredNumber)
  IF enteredNumber = 1 THEN
    RETURN 1
  ELSE
    RETURN enteredNumber + sumModule(enteredNumber - 1)

productModule(enteredNumber)
  IF enteredNumber = 1 THEN
    RETURN 1
  ELSE
    RETURN enteredNumber * productModule(enteredNumber -1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the sum module, it had 1 integer input and 1 integer output.

```
sumModule(enteredNumber)
```

If the input is 1, the output is 1

```
IF enteredNumber EQUALS 1
THEN
  RETURN 1
```

Otherwise, return the sum of the input and the output of the sum module.
The key here, it to pass 1 less than the input, so eventually the module will exit.

```
ELSE
  RETURN enteredNumber + CALL sumModule(enteredNumber - 1)
```

C++/C# syntax

```
int sumModule(int n)
{
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  return n + sumModule(n--);
}

int productModule(int n)
{
  if (n == 1)
    return 1;
  return n * productModule(n--);
}
```

Recursion saves the day! (and the wrist)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: So I am in this introductory course doing pseudocode only, so I was wondering why it is you are checking if (n ==1) and what (n--) means. Thanks for this!

Comment: (n==1) is the exit condition; without it, the function would never resolve to a value. (n--) means n - 1.

Comment: Ok, so the code that you updated would then accept all numbers that a user enters, then get the sum of all of those digits (i will add an output statement at a later time)?

Comment: Each of these modules will recursively call itself, passing in 1 less than the input, until that input is 1. When the input is not 1, it will return the input plus the result of the self-contained call. This effectively, builds up a stack of operations waiting for the result of the next one.

Comment: So I have updated the code above, have I implemented this correctly? thanks again

Comment: You missed the input declaration for the product module, but other than that it looks good!